# page unload event not working in IE 9,10 randomly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, onbeforeunload

I am trying to give alert to user if user click back button/press F5/ try to reload page.
I am using below script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var testEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
var checkEvent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload';

testEvent (checkEvent , function (e) { 
 console.log(e);
 var hdnCountValue= $("#" + '<%=hdnCount.ClientID %>').val();
 console.log(hdnCountValue);
 if (hdnCountValue!= null && hdnCountValue!= "" && hdnCountValue!= 'undefined' && parseInt(hdnCountValue) > 0) {

     var msg = 'Warning: You will lose all your data.';  
     (e || window.event).returnValue = msg ;
                           return msg;
        }
});
</script>
```

It is working fine in Firefox and chrome.

But in IE9 & 10 it is working sometimes & sometimes not.
And also in safari it works but when user choose to stay on page it changes URL, it shows previous page URL.